# Remove / from string via node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

Let's suppose I have a variable

`name  = 'product with 10/150 mg'`

How can I remove the '/' from the variable name using string functions via node.js

(Variable could have multiple '/' so is there a way to remove the value of all '/' in string?)

Can I do something like `name.replace()` ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `name.replace(/\//g,'')`   there is also [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll), but it's new and support isn't great yet

Comment: Indeed, your code above helps. g stands for global identifier, meaning all occurrences. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace / with regex
ex:

```
let name  = 'product with 10/150 mg, product with 30/250 mg, product with 40/650 mg, product with 10/150 mg, product with 20/450 mg';
let result = name.replace(/(\/)/g, ''); 
console.log(result);
```